# Frobenius stratification of imperfect fields

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, ac.commutative-algebra, arithmetic-geometry

Suppose $k$ is a (non-perfect) field of characteristic $p$, and $Fr$, its Frobenius map. I’d appreciate comments and references on the structure of the fitration/stratification of $k$ given by the images of $Fr^n$ ($n = 1,2,...$) and its uses in understanding arithmetic and geometry of varieties over $k$.